# Check working of an service in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I create a pod to test my service in kubernetes. But i didn't get anythings. Here is my command

```
kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 nginx-resolver --image=nginx
kubectl expose pod nginx-resolver --name=nginx-resolver-service --port=80 --target-port=80 --type=ClusterIP

kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 test-nslookup --image=busybox:1.28 --rm -it -- nslookup nginx-resolver-service
```

Please help me explain why. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see the log interactively, you need to set the `--restart` option of your `test-nslookup` pod to `Never` or `OnFailure`. Otherwise, kubernetes will just restart your pod indefinitely and you won't see anything.

So your last command should be :

```
kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 test-nslookup --image=busybox:1.28 -it --restart=OnFailure -- nslookup nginx-resolver-service
```

#### Why ?

Probably because of [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/27264).
It seems to have a delay of 5s before `kubectl run` actually print something.
So in order to do it without changing the `restart` option, you'll need to change your command like this (**beware of the `sleep 7`, so you'll have to wait 7seconds before seeing the logs)** :

```
kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 test-nslookup --image=busybox:1.28 -it --rm -- sh -c 'sleep 7; nslookup nginx-resolver-service'
```

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command and get things what you are thinking wrong about this cmd.

```sh
$ kubectl run --help
Create and run a particular image, possibly replicated.

 Creates a deployment or job to manage the created container(s).

Examples:
  # Start a single instance of nginx.
  kubectl run nginx --image=nginx

  # Start a single instance of hazelcast and let the container expose port 5701 .
  kubectl run hazelcast --image=hazelcast --port=5701
...
```

So, `kubectl run` cmd creates a deployment or a job

- If it is a deployment, it creates (a) first, a replicaset, (b) then Pod(s).
- If it is a job, it creates a Pod.

But you are trying to expose a Pod which name is not the correct one. You can see the name of the Pod that is/are created by the cmd `kubectl run`.

```sh
$ kubectl get pods --namespace=<namespace> | grep "nginx-resolver"
$ kubectl get pods --namespace=<namespace> | grep "test-nslookup"
```

Then use those names to expose Pod.

You can optionally expose your `Deployment`. To do so, see the help of `$ kubectl expose deployment --help`. Run:

```sh
$ kubectl expose deployment --help
Expose a resource as a new Kubernetes service.

 Looks up a deployment, service, replica set, replication controller or pod by name and uses the selector for that
resource as the selector for a new service on the specified port. A deployment or replica set will be exposed as a
service only if its selector is convertible to a selector that service supports, i.e. when the selector contains only
the matchLabels component. Note that if no port is specified via --port and the exposed resource has multiple ports, all
will be re-used by the new service. Also if no labels are specified, the new service will re-use the labels from the
resource it exposes.

 Possible resources include (case insensitive):

 pod (po), service (svc), replicationcontroller (rc), deployment (deploy), replicaset (rs)

Examples:
...
  # Create a service for an nginx deployment, which serves on port 80 and connects to the containers on port 8000.
  kubectl expose deployment nginx --port=80 --target-port=8000
...
```

Comment: @shudipata there is an exercise of mine. Here is full

```
Create an nginx pod called nginx-resolver using image nginx, expose it internally with a service called nginx-resolver-service. Test that you are able to look up the service and pod names from within the cluster. Use the image: busybox:1.28 for dns lookup. Record results in /root/nginx.svc and /root/nginx.pod
```